# Importing csv file to SQL Server Management Studio - No tables available

Tags: sql-server-2005, csv, import

I am trying to import a csv file to insert data into an existing table on my database. I go through the wizard and when it comes to select source tables and views for the destination, there are none to choose from. It just thinks I am trying to create a new table.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you selected the database to connect to properly? Are you sure you have the rights to insert into tables in that database?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Skip the wizard and use just `BULK INSERT`, here is an example:

```
BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Full example : [SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/)

Comment: This is NOT a CSV compliant solution!

Comment: @Steven, how so? the title of the linked page is: `SQL SERVER – Import CSV File Into SQL Server Using Bulk Insert – Load Comma Delimited File Into SQL Server`

Comment: Does not support line breaks in cells?

Comment: I am getting `You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.` error

Comment: It doesn't consider text qualifiers, such as quotation marks around text fields, which are important to sanitize data that may contain commas in it.

Comment: You may not have sufficient permissions to run this command - in which case - it is easy to just copy and paste the rows into SSMS by clicking "edit top 200 rows" on the table.

Answer (score 2):

Cyril's answer is along the right track. However, a true CSV-compliant solution now exists since `SQL Server 2017` (14.x) CTP 1.1.

Use this

```
BULK INSERT destinationtable
FROM 'filepath'
WITH
(
FORMAT = 'CSV'
)
GO
```

There is an issue though. If your data uses `NULL` to indicate nulls, then you'll need to remove them as MSSQLSMS will not accept `NULL` as a valid NULL value. Do a search/replace for `,NULL` to `,`.

For example (4 columns):

```
1,NULL,test,"Escaped text with comma, this works"
```

must be formatted like this:

```
1,,test,"Escaped text with comma, this works"
```

See [SQL won't insert null values with BULK INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942538/sql-wont-insert-null-values-with-bulk-insert) for information on NULL insertion problems.

You can go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

We do have multiple options:

1. using dts wizard
2. by programming

to know dts path or code in c# go through it

<strike>http://sqlcopy.blogspot.in/2012/07/bulk-sql-to-sql-sql-to-csv-csv-to-sql.html</strike> <sup>(dead link)</sup>