# Bulk insert null into table from csv file in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to bulk insert from a csv file to a table.
This is my code for creating the table

```
create table customers 
(
    customerNumber int not null,
    customerName varchar(50) not null,
    salesRepNumber int null, 
    primary key(customerNumber)
);
```

This is the example of the csv file:

```
1001,John,1121
1002,James,1122
1003,Jonas,1123
1004,Jane,1124,
1005,Tom,1125,
1006,Bob,1126
1007,Thomas,NULL
```

This is the code for inserting data into the table:

```
BULK INSERT customers
FROM 'D:\Customers.csv'
WITH (fieldterminator=',', rowterminator='\n')
```

And I get these errors:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 7, column 12 (salesRepNumber).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 22, column 12 (salesRepNumber).

I am not so sure about how to bulk insert 'NULL' into a table and I am only supposed to use int datatype for the salesRep.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942538/sql-wont-insert-null-values-with-bulk-insert

Comment: Hi, I changed the "NULL" to empty, but am still not able to insert all the data.
The code is 

`BULK INSERT customers
FROM 'D:\DENG\Customers.csv'
WITH (fieldterminator=',', rowterminator='\n',KEEPNULLS)`

I still get this error message: 



Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 37, column 12 (salesRepNumber).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 110, column 12 (salesRepNumber).

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18, the version is 18.6